# How to run this function in a seperate process on Windows?

Tags: python

I am trying to run this code in the background (from command line) on Windows using python 2.7:

```py
import httpimport

mod = httpimport.load('module name','URL')
```

Everything works, but the process lingers when launched  and only ctrl + c will end it. I am looking to start an independent process from this in the background.

I have read that multiprocess can come useful here but I would need some pointers if I may.
Any suggestions ?

EDIT: I may add this is a script which is calling another python script from URL. From the answers below I gathered that I might need to change my remote script first.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to run your process in the background you can use `spawnl`

```
import os
os.spawnl(os.P_DETACH, 'python code.py "module name" "url"')
```

but you need to be cautious, you can't kill the process if you don't knew it's pid or check where it is running via task manager

check for more: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.spawnl

for your code (for exemple code.py):

```
import httpimport
from sys import argv
name, module_name, URL = argv # here you get the module name and URL from the argument given from before
mod = httpimport.load(module_name , URL)
```

Comment: I am aware of this one but how would you include my code in your proposal ?

Comment: I have tried this one, same situation. I might need to amend my remote script according to this, will try. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: OK I have tried your modified code as well. Nothing is happening when I execute the one with os.spawnl.